# iPhone restore AudioSession in Play&Record after playing youtube video

Tags: ios, youtube, voip, background-process, audiosession

I have a problem about managing AudioSession (set as Play&Record category) interruptions in my VoIP app in iOS 5.x.
When I have a call in progress, going background and starting youtube app, the audio session begin-interruption occurs and I can put in pause the current call.

The problem is when I return to foreground and want to reactive my call (WITHOUT killing youtube app, simply putting it in background previously): no end-interruption callback occurs and even if I force to set active my previous audioSession, it returns error.
I check if the audio resources are maybe in use by other process (with  AudioSessionGetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying,...) but they don't.
If I kill manually youtube app the end-interruption occurs instead and there's no problem.

Since normally no one kills manually the app, how can i restore the audioSession of my call??
I've checked other examples and Viber works correctly and can "intercepts" in some way the end-interruption.

Another strange behaviour is that if I set also "allowMixing" category in my AudioSession, it is completely ignored in iOS 5.x (youtube takes control of audio resources) while in iOS 4.x it works as it should (that is I listen in contemporary the audio call and youtube mixed).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by stopping and (re-) starting my audio unit in the interruption callback.

Comment: The problem is that the (end) interruption does NOT occur. So how can I know the right moment to restart the audio unit?